# Making very small mortises/grooves in wood

Tags: wood, hand-tools

I'm wondering if there is a best way to make such holes in wood, size 2mm x 10mm. Should I use small chisels or any other approach you recommend?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking! I missed one key detail in this and had to delete my previous Comments because they weren't about what you asked \*doh* So anyway, I think there's really no choice here but to do this with hand tools. I can't even envisage a process that relied on power tools that could achieve this (other than a good laser, as long as quite shallow recesses were acceptable). You could drill out some of the excess wood to help start the process but given the tiny scale here I'm not sure if you'd actually be saving time.

Comment: So, *"Should I use small chisels"* I think there's actually no choice here IF no laser. However there is a catch in that 2mm woodworking chisels aren't made as far as I know, so you'd need to make one or modify an existing chisel just for this. There are craft chisels however, but not sure how they'd hold up to what you have to do in the woods you choose to use.... and sharpening them would be *extremely* challenging, bordering on impossible for some people. Based on this, how does getting this done by laser sound?

Comment: Judging by the little metal chisels strewn around in the photo I assume they are custom made from round stock (you could even use drill bits). @Graphus's point on the challenge of sharpening these chisels is spot on, and I would add that you'd need to fabricate them to begin with.

Comment: There are small chisels for plastic models - for example "Tamiya Modeling Flat Chisel Blade 2mm" (which I own) - it's not ground like a normal woodworking chisel (more like a lathe tool), but for cutting small grooves or holes just like on your picture, it works quite well and I use it a lot. As for sharpening: light touches with fine stone or stroping is enough if you do it often. The downside is the price and it doesn't come with a handle - they sell the handle separately, but it's probably better to make your own (which is what I did).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I found 2mm chisel from Kirschen (model: 1001002)

Comment: OMG someone *does* make a 2mm chisel commercially! I'm shocked. Perfect style for this type of work compared to the narrow hobby chisels I've seen (much better blade geometry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use small chisels or any other approach you recommend?

I think cutting by laser is arguably *the* way to do these, assuming the cost were not an issue. The results in all cases are going to be essentially perfect, requiring no time-consuming tricky and tedious small-scale work with hand tools.

Assuming no laser however, should you use small chisels? Yes, partly; I think there's actually no choice but to cut these by hand, using a chisel among other tools — defining the long edges by cutting carefully with a knife seems prudent.

I was under the impression that no 2mm woodworking chisels were made, but the OP found them made by Kirschen (AKA Two Cherries), their [1001002 Firmer Chisel](https://www.kirschen.de/en/Mortise_Firmer-Chisels_p2.html). These are quoted as having very good hardness, Rc61, are fitted with hornbeam handles with steel ferrules, and reinforced at the butt end with a steel ring.

Care should be exercised with chisels this narrow not to stress them sideways too much, or at all; especially at high hardnesses narrow chisels are prone to snapping.

It should go without saying but careful layout/marking will be absolutely key to accuracy here if working by hand.

**Method, a 'cheat'**
If I were doing some of these — and regardless of whether I was using hand tools or had them done by laser — I'd be very inclined to do a sort of cheat and split the wooden block by resawing, to leave a thick base piece and a thinner 'skin' that I'd work on separately.

- Resaw the blocks perhaps 80/20 or 90/10 (chosen based on desired mortise depth).
- Smooth the mating surfaces to that they will glue back together perfectly; this can be done by hand planing or by sanding.
- Cut grooves into the thinner piece, chiselling or lasering right through (instead of the 'slightly' more tricky operation of cutting mortises).
- Glue the block pieces back together, applying just enough glue to both surfaces to ensure a good bond while minimising cleanup.
- Fill the recesses as you prefer, then make flush and clean up the top face.
- Clean up all edges.
- Apply finish of choice, done.

In either case you'd start with blocks slightly thicker than the final dimensions. 1mm or so should be enough. This is to allow for flushing at the end of course but also cleanup of any extraneous marks from laying out, or scorching from the laser.